# Python - have a function output multiple data frames

Tags: python, function

I would like to achieve the following.

1. I would like the function to output a separate data frame for each stock for example
2. I would like to save each data frame to a separate csv

the code doesnt work and i am unable to output the and save the separate csvs. Can you help me output separate dataframes and export the respective CSVS?

```
    def getdata(stock: str):
        # Company Quote Group of Items
        company_quote = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/{stock}?apikey=demo")
        company_quote = company_quote.json()
        share_price = float("{0:.2f}".format(company_quote[0]['price']))
        
        # Balance Sheet Group of Items    
        BS = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/income-statement/{stock}?period=quarter&limit=400&apikey=demo")
        BS = BS.json()
        #Total Debt
        debt = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(BS[0]['totalDebt'])/10**9))
        #Total Cash
        cash = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(BS[0]['cashAndShortTermInvestments'])/10**9))
       
        # Income Statement Group of Items
        IS = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/income-statement/{stock}?period=quarter&limit=400&apikey=demo")
        IS = IS.json()
        # Most Recent Quarterly Revenue
        qRev = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(IS[0]['revenue'])/10**9))
       
        # Company Profile Group of Items
        company_info = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/profile/{stock}?apikey=demo")
        company_info = company_info.json()
        # Chief Executive Officer
        ceo = (company_info[0]['ceo'])
        return (share_price, cash, debt, qRev, ceo)
    
    stocks = ('AAPL')
    d = {}
    for stock in stocks:
        df[stock] = pd.DataFrame(getdata, columns=['Share Price','Total Cash', 'Total Debt', 'Q3 2019 Revenue', 'CEO'], index=tickers)
    print(d)
```

Comment: Okay, and what is your question about your goal?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.  "It doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the offending values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. In essence  you should be able to copy paste and run the code now. I have replaced the links with demo links also trimmed down stocks list to just one company aapl. So if it works for aapl it shold also work for other tickers that i add to the stock list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question. But if the fact is that you want a different DataFrame for each ticker, here is a solution.

Instead of :

```
for stock in stocks:
    df[stock] = pd.DataFrame(....
```

Try:

```
for stock in stocks:
    globals()['df_%s' %stock] = pd.DataFrame(...
    # And to save it, inside the loop
    globals()['df_%s' %stock].to_csv(stock+'.csv')
```

EDIT:

Thanx for the add. Here is the code

```
import joblib
from joblib import Parallel,delayed
import requests
import pandas as pd

def getdata(stock):
    
    # Company Quote Group of Items
    company_quote = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/quote/{stock}?apikey=demo")
    company_quote = company_quote.json()
    share_price = float("{0:.2f}".format(company_quote[0]['price']))
    
    # Balance Sheet Group of Items    
    BS = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/balance-sheet-statement/{stock}?period=quarter&limit=400&apikey=demo")
    BS = BS.json()
    #Total Debt
    debt = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(BS[0]['totalDebt'])/10**9))
    #Total Cash
    cash = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(BS[0]['cashAndShortTermInvestments'])/10**9))
    
    # Income Statement Group of Items
    IS = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/income-statement/{stock}?period=quarter&limit=400&apikey=demo")
    IS = IS.json()
    # Most Recent Quarterly Revenue
    qRev = float("{0:.2f}".format(float(IS[0]['revenue'])/10**9))
    
    # Company Profile Group of Items
    company_info = requests.get(f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/profile/{stock}?apikey=demo")
    company_info = company_info.json()
    # Chief Executive Officer
    ceo = (company_info[0]['ceo'])

    globals()['df_%s' %stock] = pd.DataFrame({'symbol':[stock],'debt':[debt],'cash':[cash],'qRev':[qRev],'ceo':[ceo]})

    globals()['df_%s' %stock].to_csv(stock+'.csv')
    return(globals()['df_%s' %stock])

stocks = ['AAPL'] #, 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'T', 'CSCO', 'INTC', 'ORCL', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'TSLA', 'NVDA']

number_of_cpu = joblib.cpu_count()
delayed_funcs = [delayed(getdata)(stock) for stock in stocks]
parallel_pool = Parallel(n_jobs=number_of_cpu,prefer="processes") # processes threads
globals()['df_%s' %stock] = parallel_pool(delayed_funcs)
df_AAPL
```

OUTPUT

[image]

[image]

It isn't necessary to return the DataFrame, as you save it in the function. But I did it to show you the possibility.

Comment: Thx lumber Jack. It is as you say I want a different data frame for different  each ticker. I tried your solution. I get the following error "TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'AAPL' was passed"

Comment: Without a constant (minimalist) example, it will be hard for me to help more. But if you edit it, I'll try to help you .The idea is to put the creation of the DataFrame in the function, and to use multiprocessor to make_it. As you save It in the function, you not even have to return it, but, if you prefer, you of course can

Comment: I got the same feedback from the others.. I have now edited the code in theproblem description to include the demo links instead of the ones with my api keys. So you should be able to copy paste and run the code. The demo links only work for one stock that is aapl. I am guessing that should suffice to replicate the problem. Thx again for your help and patience....

Comment: if it's ok, don't forget to mark your answer to end this thread, other community members can benefit from it.